# Problems when using relative time in ElasticSearch Transform queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch as a backend for metrics collected by various applications. The setup looks like this:

1. Apps write data to a *rawdata* index where there is a 24 hour retention implemented via ILM policies + index templates
2. Then, i use an ES transform to continously write aggregations of this data to separate *hourly* indices. One of the reasons i opted for this approach is because not all of the metadata in the raw data is interesting to keep for more than 24 hours, thus this second stage is "opt-in" per field.
3. These hourly indices are configured with a rollover ILM policy to ensure indidual shards do not get too big.

This works well but i would like to make an improvement - i want it to be possible to view this all of this data as one continuous range of values in a single query, *without there being any overlapping data*. Without any extra modification this will obviously happen as the transform will instantly roll up any new data and the indices will therefore overlap.

So my approach of solving this was using a relative timestamp in the query section of the transform. That is, the transform should only consider values that are older than 23 hours. My idea was that the following would happen:

1. New data comes in to the rawdata index
2. Once that data becomes more than 23 hours old, the transform will "detect" it and start rolling it up and store it in the hourly index
3. One hour later, this data is deleted from the rawdata index and the cycle repeats

In (my) theory this should work. However, what actually happens is that huge gaps in the rolled up data start appearing. It seems like there is only a one hour window per day where the transform actually finds any data, picture below:

[image]

This is what the transform query looks like:

```
"source": {
      "index": [
        "rawdata_index"
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "lte": "now-23h/h"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    },
```

Why is the behaviour like this? And is there another way of achieving what i want?